# Postgres Crosstab throwing error about tuple, yet return columns match type?

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I keep getting this error returned, but the types match as I checked with pg_typeof for the columns.  They returned text and bigint.

```
ERROR: return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
SQL state: 42601
```

Here is the test table definition

```
create table reader_event
(
   reader_event_id serial,
   reader_name text,
   event_type varchar(25),
   event_date timestamp,
   metric_key text,
   metric_value bigint
)
```

And here are the inserts

```
insert into reader_event(reader_name, event_type, event_date, metric_key, metric_value)
 values('t', 'insert', now(),                    'followers',    10),
       ('t', 'upate', now()+ interval '1' day,   'followers',    20),
       -- Add New Metric
       ('t', 'insert', now(),                    'subscribers',  10000),
       ('t', 'update', now()+ interval '2' day,  'followers',    9999),
       ('t', 'update', now()+ interval '3' day,  'subscribers',  17),
       -- Add new metric
       ('t', 'insert', now(),                    'reads',        9999);

 insert into reader_event(reader_name, event_type, event_date, metric_key, metric_value)
  values('a', 'insert', now(),                   'followers',    10),
        ('a', 'upate',  now(),                   'followers',    20),
        ('a', 'upate',  now()+ interval '1' day, 'followers',    230);
```

And the query that returns the error.  I search google and StackOverflow and I am stumped.

```
// Show new current events.
select * from crosstab(        
 'select b.reader_name, b.metric_key, a.metric_value
    from
       (select max(reader_event_id) as reader_event_id
             , reader_name
             , metric_key
             , max(event_date) as event_date 
                 from reader_event
                    group by reader_name,metric_key
                      order by 2, 3, 4
       ) b
       inner join reader_event a 
           on a.reader_event_id = b.reader_event_id
            order by 1,2'
       ) AS (reader_name text,metric_key text,metric_value bigint)
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have understood the point of the `crosstab`.
`(reader_name text,metric_key text,metric_value bigint)` is the input of the crosstab. Is it defined by:

1. row name (returned in the 1st column of the crosstab)
2. category name (not returned but used for ordering the categories)
3. category value (returned starting in the 2nd column of the crosstab)

You are expected to specify the output, which is in your case:
`(reader_name text,metric_value1 bigint,metric_value2 bigint,metric_value3 bigint)`

Unless you add a `WHERE` clause to ensure not more than N values are returned by the inner query, more values will need to be added as your database grows.